# Remove modalViewController from view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, modalviewcontroller

I have a view which pulls in another view using this code:

```
secondView = [[SecondView alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondView];
navigationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
[navigationController release];
```

The cancel button on this 2nd view has this:

```
[self.navigationController.modalViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

But it doesn't appear to do anything. The view is still there and I can still interact with it. How do i remove it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try:

```
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

Comment: simple as that! thanks! never used modalviewcontroller before so didn't realise that.

Comment: Any way to give it a different dismiss animation?

Comment: try changing the modalTransitionStyle property

Comment: iOS7 Update: [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];